# Make multiple bootable partitions on 1 usb. Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, live-usb

I would like to dual boot Windows 7 alongside my Ubuntu 18.04 system, However the programme in Ubuntu 18.04 are unable to correctly mount my ISO files to my USB.

I tried using **UNetbootin** and using disk backup, both failed as system cannot find boot. 
It worked was when I used a windows computer I borrowed, with the same ISO files.

I have a 1 TB USB with three partitions:
1. 5GB for Windows installation
2. 5GB for Ubuntu installation 
3. The remaining is a NTFS storage.

Comment: I would increase the windows partition, the windows install is probably ~10 GB, so it wouldn't even fit.

Answer (score 0):

Try again. I succeeded by writing the iso on a DVD. I've got Windows 7 and Ubuntu 18.04 and this one runs much faster than Windows.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should increase the size for Windows 7 partition to somewhat like 20 GB to 25 GB.

**Make another bootable USB for your Linux installation.**
Install Windows in your Windows petition and then install Ubuntu with the Live USB.
Select the respective partition and mount root directory to it, then you should mount your `/home` directory to remaining NTFS space.

P.S.
You should make Linux `swap space` as well.
Since you are sharing the data storage partition for your Windows and Ubuntu, make sure never to hibernate your Windows. 
Because the changes made by Ubuntu will not be reflected back in Windows.

Note : I don't recommend using only three partitions for dual-boot as this will cause a lot of problem in future.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a swap on a USB stick. And most devices have enough ram these days to be able to run without a swap.